# Reading CSV data and inserting into SQL in C#.NET

Tags: c#

I need to design windows based application by which customer can upload a csv file. Form consist of three buttons Upload a file, Delete a data before adding/inserting into table in SQL and Synchronize the data with same primary key/data.

Comment: what's the question here? Or did you expect someone to code all of that for you?

Answer (score 0):

Take look at this using `SqlBulkCopy` - http://www.csvreader.com/code/cs/upload_csv.php

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to read CSV is to create a DSN using the MS Text Driver.  Then you can read the CSV file like a database table.  Something like this:

```
        OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=Stack");
        conn.Open();
        OdbcCommand foo = new OdbcCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [stack.csv]",conn);
        IDataReader dr = foo.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            int cols = dr.GetSchemaTable().Rows.Count;
            for (int i=0; i<cols; i++)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dr[i].ToString());
            }
        }
```